# Как выйти с этого сайта?

Tags: поддержка, аутентификация

Хочу зайти под другим аккаунтом. Как выйти?

Comment: Вы только что спалились насчёт использования множественных учёток. Оставайтесь на месте, пативен уже выехал.

Comment: ахахахах. можете забанить второй или первый)

Answer (score 4):

Слева вверху выпадающая менюшка StackExchange, в ней справа сверху - "выйти"

Comment: принять не смогу, потому как я уже буду под другим акком)

Comment: @Jenkamen не беда, вопрос все равно будет перемещен на Мету и закрыт как дубликат, репа снимется емнип ) А лучше вы его сами удалите сразу сейчас

Comment: а мне как-то пофиг)