# Ответ в вопросе, закрытом как дубликат устарел. Что делать?

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

На мысль натолкнули недавно всплывшие дубликаты на Мете. Например, вопрос [Как выйти с этого сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3514/176217) закрыт как дубликат. Однако он уже содержит один ответ, который на текущий момент устарел, так как дизайн шапки сайта был изменён.

Стоит ли править ответы в таких вопросах? Может надо перенести все ответы под один конкретный вопрос и править их там? Но зачем нам множество одинаковых ответов, требующих правки при очередном изменении дизайна? Может стоит вовсе удалить ответы под вопросам-дубликатами и держать в порядке один единственный ответ из незакрытого вопроса? Ваши предложения?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ответ требует правки связи с изменением стандарта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5890/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: Где что устарело? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5511/178988 - скриншот актуален.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня ссылка в сообщении на дубликат, где ответ устарел.

Comment: @alexolut, так он же и сам закрыт как дубликат ауктуального. Это раз. А ещё там нет скриншотов, которые могли бы устареть, а текст, вроде, актуальный.

Comment: @Qwertiy нет. Не актуальный. Шапка же изменилась с тех пор.

Comment: Кнопка SE, внутри справа ссылка на выход. Что не так?

Comment: @Qwertiy "Слева вверху" про кнопку там сказано. Вроде бы не так много слов, чтоб запутаться.